# How to ad-hoc filter hosts (target managed nodes) in Ansible using facts on CLI level

Tags: ansible

On SaltStack one can execute:

```
salt -G 'os:CentOS' test.version
```

`-G` means filter managed nodes using *grains*. SaltStack's *Grains* is an equivalent of Ansible's *facts*. SaltStack is caching grains on controller, so this functionality is not a problem. Ansible has some facts caching too but it looks like there is not much use of it. Is something like this possible with Ansible?

I know it can be done using custom dynamic inventory modules or by embedding some code inside playbook, but I'm looking for something more ad-hoc.

Comment: This is a functionality you will find in [Tower or AWX](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/inventories.html#smart-inventories) but not in Ansible per se, no.

Comment: Tank you @β.εηοιτ.βε Could you post it as an answer? A would accept it.